# Combining two strings to form a new string

Tags: string, python-3.x

I am trying to write a program that asks the user for two strings and creates a new string by merging the two together (take one letter from each string at a time). I am not allowed to use slicing. If the user enters abcdef and xyzw, program should build the string: axbyczdwef

```
s1 = input("Enter a string: ")
s2 = input("Enter a string: ")
i = 0
print("The new string is: ",end='')
while i < len(s1):
    print(s1[i] + s2[i],end='')
    i += 1
```

The problem I am having is if one of the strings is longer than the other I get an index error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do your `while i < min(len(s1), len(s2))`, and then make sure to print out the remaining part of the string.

OR

`while i < MAX(len(s1), len(s2))` and then only print `s1[i]` if `len(s1) > i` and only print `s2[i]` if `len(s2) > i` in your loop.

Answer (score 1):

I think zip_longest in Python 3's itertools gives you the most elegant answer here:

```
import itertools

s1 = input("Enter a string: ")
s2 = input("Enter a string: ")

print("The new string is: {}".format(
      ''.join(i+j for i,j in itertools.zip_longest(s1, s2, fillvalue=''))))
```

[Here's the docs, with what zip_longest is doing behind the scenes.](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest)

Comment: Definitely a better answer than mine, though perhaps less inline with the educational goal of the assignment.

Comment: Danke Daniel! :) Oops, I left in her original `i` which was unused, thanks for bumping this for me. :)